# Breaking a determinant into eight pieces

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

From Strang, *Introduction to Linear Algebra, 4th ed.* p. 250. This is an example whose answer is given in the text but I'm confused. I've paraphrased and corrected what I think is a typo in the first matrix (*row 3 + row 3* changed to *row 3 + row 2*).

*How is the determinant of M related to the determinant of A? Rows of M are combinations of the rows of A.*

$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}  \text{row 1 + row 3} \\ \text{row 2 + row 1} \\ \text{row 3 + row 2} \\  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

*M can be split into eight matrices:*

$$
\det M=
\begin{vmatrix}  \text{row 1 + row 3} \\ \text{row 2 + row 1} \\ \text{row 3 + row 2} \\  \end{vmatrix} 
=  \begin{vmatrix} \text{row 1} \\ \text{row 2} \\ \text{row 3} \end{vmatrix}
+ \begin{vmatrix} \text{row 3} \\ \text{row 2} \\ \text{row 3} \end{vmatrix}
+ \begin{vmatrix} \text{row 1} \\ \text{row 1} \\ \text{row 3} \end{vmatrix}
+ \cdots 
+ \begin{vmatrix} \text{row 3} \\ \text{row 1} \\ \text{row 2} \end{vmatrix} 
$$ 
*All but the first and last have repeated rows and zero determinant.*

**My question:** By the rule that $$\begin{vmatrix} a + a^\prime  & b + b^\prime \\ c & d \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} a^\prime  & b^\prime \\ c & d \end{vmatrix}$$ I'd have thought that the first three matrices (before the ellipsis) would suffice to produce the determinant of M. Why do we need the other bunch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's apply the rule you quoted once:
$$
\det M=\left|
\begin{matrix}
\text{row 1}+\text{row 3}\\
\text{row 2}+\text{row 1}\\
\text{row 3}+\text{row 2}\\
\end{matrix}
\right|
=
\left|
\begin{matrix}
\text{row 1}\\
\text{row 2}+\text{row 1}\\
\text{row 3}+\text{row 2}\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
\text{row 3}\\
\text{row 2}+\text{row 1}\\
\text{row 3}+\text{row 2}\\
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$
Now you apply the rule to the second row, and it gives $2\cdot 2=4$ terms. Lastly apply it to the third row to get all $2\cdot 2\cdot 2=8$ terms.

Each time you apply the rule to a row, the number of terms doubles.

Comment: Super. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.